# VBA-M always in turbo

Tags: 14.04, emulation

I recently installed VBA-M from the SourceForge .deb file. Unfortunately, VBA is stuck in a turbo mode of some sorts. The speed is always on a whopping 500% or more. As you can imagine this makes most games unplayable. Any way to fix this?

Version number is VBA-M 2.0.0-SVN

Answer (score 0):

Click Options then Speed > then throttle, and then set the throttle to 100%, that should fix it! I was bit worried that no one found it yet either :y